# Difference between the similar databases at Postgres 9.1 and Postgres 9.3

Tags: postgresql, indexing, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3

I have a database at Postgres 9.1 which is well optimised (indexes). When I make dump from it and restore it to another server with Postgres 9.3, it works very slow. What is the difference between these versions? Should I disable any features in Postgres 9.3?

Comment: detail on resotration process needed. configs are equal? why not `pg_upgrade`?..

Comment: Did you [`analyze`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-analyze.html) the 9.3 database?

Comment: Try to run `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` on a statement in both databases and see if there are differences.

Comment: Version 9.1 to 9.3 contains major release. It is always recommended that you rebuild the indexes after migrating. And 9.3 contains some major improvements like index_only scans and etc. Please refer [this](https://www.postgresql.org/about/featurematrix/) for more info on the changes.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. But "analyze" command don't anything useful. As well as "reindex" command. What I did - I have added some additional indexes for DB in 9.3.